# How to save state of variables between script calls from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, testcomplete

I have several scripts in TestComplete which are preparing system(initialization of some variables) and another scripts with actual steps. 
Main problem is - calls to functions in TestComplete scripts using Visual Studio treated as separate runs by TestComplete without saving temporary results.
If I create keyword in TestComplete and run it from Visual Studio - of course everything works fine, but I want to run separate functions and save their state between calls. Is it possible?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in persistent project variables. These variables keeps values between test runs. Please find more information on this functionality in the [Project And Project Suite Variables - Overview](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/74914/) TestComplete help topic.